# How can I let somone over ssh have access to pulseaudio?

Tags: ssh, pulseaudio, x11-forwarding, multiseat

I recently had a really good post here where I was able to figure out how to setup virtualgl and use it with X11 forwarding in ssh.  I am using it to make a kind of multiseat setup.  I only have one sound card at the moment so I am trying to figure out how to let the remote user get access to the sound card over SSH for their gaming.  I am only doing soundless stuff on the desktop when they are gaming so I dont need the sound.  The problem is the sound only goes to the local user .

So to explain better, I am logged in as user1 locally.  The user who will be accessing the desktop through ssh is user2.  Only things user1 does has sound output, but I want user2 to be able to have access the sound card instead.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

user2 will be accessing my computer on an ubuntu laptop.

Also I was wondering if I get a second sound card can I have an audio output going to each of the two users?

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Multiseat + PulseAudio is not easy. You may get some help from this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192522/how-do-i-configure-sound-with-pulseaudio-and-multiseat